# When I order files by an unusual meta column, does the computer read headers of the files or just a structured list like a data table?

Tags: filesystems, search-indexing

Is there a file system which will reduce the need for indexing files and saves the meta headers automatically on the disk? It would work like a hardware acceleration for indexing all files for some cost of write-update time, by making searches faster.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes
this is what I have found so far

Comment: have you looked at [btrfs](http://lwn.net/Articles/342892/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link,

> Extended file attributes is a file system feature that enables users
>   to associate computer files with metadata not interpreted by the
>   filesystem

Unless I'm misreading that, the metadata stored in extended file attributes function essentially as post-it-notes attached to the file, but not *in* the file.  As such, they are stored *with* the file, and wouldn't necessarily have any affect on indexing.

Unless this metadata is something that the indexing routine and the [notice changes to files] system of whatever system you're using would actually be looking for, making changes to this metadata won't necessarily do *anything*.